# JPA inheritance: unique constraint per class

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, jpa

The (concrete) base class of my hierarchy has a field. I want that field to be unique per class in the hierarchy.

So if instance1 of BaseClass has myField = 1, instance1 of SubClass can also have myField = 1. However instance2 of BaseClass is not allowed to have myField = 1.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What inheritance strategy are you using?

Comment: That's an unique index (or even id) per class?

Comment: unique index. @Perception I guess I just need to use table_per_class and it works?

Comment: @beginner_ - yes, that's why I was asking. If you have control over the database schema then table-per-class is what you want to go with.

Comment: You could also use a single table, and have a unique constraint on [discriminator_column, my_field].

Comment: JB good idea, however I need not null constraints on subclasses so that won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use table_per_class strategy.